# I am facing an error while installing new packages in R

Tags: r

I am completely new to R programming and when I tried to install a package "UsingR", I received an error. I used the below code:

`install.packages("UsingR")`

and the output was:

> unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
> cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
> argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default

Comment: Can you open the link https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/ in your browser? The error message makes it sounds like access to that website might be blocked by your network. You need full access to the internet to install packages.

Comment: Thank you, that was really the issue. There was a restriction in my institution wifi. And it worked in Another network.